# Problema com execução do EventListener

Tags: javascript, eventos, javascript-eventos, event-listener

```
if((document.getElementById("avatarZica").innerHTML == "")){
        document.getElementById("avatarLegal").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("avatarZica").innerHTML = "<canvas class='emscripten' id='canvas' oncontextmenu='event.preventDefault()' height='400px' width='250px'></canvas>";

            var imported = document.createElement('script');
            imported.src = 'avatar/Release/UnityLoader.js';
            document.head.appendChild(imported);
            console.log(document.getElementById("avatarZica").innerHTML);
        });
    }
```

Código sendo usado dentro do arquivo index.php. Fiz a condição para que se fosse a primeira vez que o usuário clicasse então ele executaria o código acima criando o avatar para traduzir o conteúdo da página, mas se eu clicar novamente dá um erro falando que o arquivo já existe e trava a página. Aparentemente o código está certo e a condição também, mas toda vez que eu clico no objeto ele tenta criar novamente o arquivo e dá erro por conta do Unity. Agradeço desde já. 
Att,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troca a ordem das duas primeiras linhas, assim o `if` é corrido a cada `click`. Como tens o `if` é corrido uma vez e o `addEventListener` corre depois sempre com as mesmas condições.

```js
document.getElementById("avatarLegal").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var avatarZica = document.getElementById("avatarZica");
  if ((avatarZica.innerHTML == "")) {
    avatarZica.innerHTML = "<canvas class='emscripten' id='canvas' oncontextmenu='event.preventDefault()' height='400px' width='250px'></canvas>";
    var imported = document.createElement('script');
    imported.src = 'avatar/Release/UnityLoader.js';
    document.head.appendChild(imported);
  }
});
```